# how to fix this error: cannot access zzbgl class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

Tags: android

when i am run the program i found this error 
class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbgl not found

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
   // buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.zone.zone1"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
       exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    ///////////sdk///////
    implementation'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    implementation'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    implementation'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:library:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
    implementation'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.15.3'
    implementation'junit:junit:4.12'





}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: You have to fix a couple of errors before moving forward with the actual problem, the first espresso is for testing it should be androidTestImplementation, junit is for testing as well it should be testImplementation. And I think google services plugin should be on the top below android plugin start with that and see if anything changes

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest versions of google play service and use the same version for all google services dependencies.

Use this link for lastest versions https://mvnrepository.com/

EDIT:

change this

```
  implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
```

to this

```
  implementation'com.google.android.gms:play-services:16.0.0'
```